# score script plugin in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I implemented a scoring plug-in to skip some documents in the search results, and the actual business is to skip the user's read. Plug-in address https://github.com/yzlq99/ElasticsearchPlugin

**Problem:** Performance issues, performance will be poor when too much document data is searched out. Because every document will execute the plugin script

**Optimization ideas:** The optimization idea is whether to control the paging execution script. For example, if I take 50 items per page, then as long as I meet the conditions and do not get the first 50 items in the skip list, I will stop the script and return the data directly. (Now the script will be executed on all documents regardless of page breaks or not, Is there any way to control it?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using FilterScript instead of ScoreScript?
It should fit your use case much better.

I also created a plugin that uses RoaringBitmap with Elasticsearch (with FilterScript instead) and didn't see major performance issues for big lists. (the repo also contains a link to a benchmark blog post).

Repo: https://github.com/lsena/fastfilter-elasticsearch-plugin

I'll be updating it soon with further performance updates too.